# Single SQL query which should display sysdates as following

Tags: sql, oracle

Output required

```
Sysdate
Sysdate+1
Sysdate+2
Sysdate+3
```

It should be similar to the output of below query,

```
SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL

UNION

SELECT SYSDATE+1 FROM DUAL

UNION

. . .

. . .

so on,
```

but should be done without using UNION, help.

Comment: `SELECT ... UNION SELECT ...;` is a single query.

Comment: Ok, I mean withou using UNION :)

Comment: You just need to learn about **[ROW GENERATOR](http://lalitkumarb.com/2015/04/15/generate-date-month-name-week-number-day-number-between-two-dates-in-oracle-sql/)** method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CONNECT BY`:

```
SELECT SYSDATE + LEVEL - 1
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4;
```

Or you can use a Common Table Expression

```
WITH CTE( "Date", lvl ) AS
(
  SELECT SYSDATE, 1 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SYSDATE + lvl, lvl + 1 FROM CTE WHERE lvl <= 3
)
SELECT "Date" FROM CTE;
```